# How to call method of second parent class using method of child class in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, ipython, multiple-inheritance

Below is my code:

```
class Parent1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "!!! ___initialization Parent1___ !!!"

    def method(self):
        print "*** method of Parent1 is called ***"


class Parent2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "!!! ___initialization Parent2___ !!!"

    def method(self):
        print "*** method of Parent2 is called ***"

class Child(Parent1,Parent2):
    def __init__(self):
        print "!!! ___initialization Child___ !!!"

    def method(self):
        super(Child,self).method()
        print "*** method of Child is called ***"


Ch = Child()
Ch.method()
```

I want to call `method()` of `Parent2` class using object of child class. Conditions are only child class object should be created and no change in  child class declaration (`class Child(Parent1,Parent2):` should not changed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Parent2.method(self)
```

That's all you need - the `instance.method()` is just syntactic sugar for `ClassName.method(instance)`, so all you need to do is call it without the syntactic sugar and it'll do fine.

I changed the `Child` class to this:

```
class Child(Parent1,Parent2):
    def __init__(self):
        print "!!! ___initialization Child___ !!!"

    def method(self):
        super(Child,self).method()
        print "*** method of Child is called ***"
        Parent2.method(self)
```

And:

```
# Out:
$ python c.py
!!! ___initialization Child___ !!!
*** method of Parent1 is called ***
*** method of Child is called ***
*** method of Parent2 is called ***
```

You get the expected output perfectly fine.

Comment: You might as well change `super(Child, self).method()` to `Parent1.method(self)` as well. This class hierarchy is not designed to use `super` properly.

Comment: @James: Thanks for the solution. Is this the only way to do it? Is there any other way? Can't it be done using super() or decorator?

Comment: @Praveenkumar I'm not aware of one, but I'm by no means an expert on Python inheritance, it's possible there's some way I don't know of.

Comment: @James. Yes I will. :)